# Web Scraping and Mixed Content

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, polymer, mixed

I'm trying to make a website using Polymer that provides some utilities to fantasy football players. Part of this challenge is importing a member's league and running some analysis on it.

My website is secure (HTTPS). The website with the member's league information is insecure (HTTP). Whenever I try to scrape data from the provided website, I receive this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure HTML Import 'http://www.theirwebsite.com'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I've scoured the internet trying to find a way to scrape team data off their website, so that I can manipulate that data on my end.

Given that I am using Polymer, is there any way I can access data that is on an insecure website?

Answer (score 0):

You will *not* be able to request a webpage over HTTP on the client side (i.e. in the browser, in JavaScript) if your website was loaded over HTTPS. Not much you can do about it.

An option would be to have a backend (on the server side, for instance PHP or NodeJS) make the scraping and return the result to your client-side application.

Another option, maybe simpler if you prefer doing the processing on the client side, would be to make your server proxy your request and send you back the result. For instance, if you wanted to access `http://example.com`, you could have a script *proxy.php* that you can call using the URL `https://yourwebsite.com/proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`(1) in your JavaScript code. This script would simply load the website and give you back its HTML code. (See for instance [cURL](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if you want to do this with PHP, or [request](https://github.com/request/request) if your prefer Node.)

*(1) the %3A corresponds to an url-encoded slash*